# Are There Rules for Tiny PCs?

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size

I am working with a player to make a homonculus companion that uses weapons, and I am curious if there have been any supplements to 5th edition that talks about Tiny sized characters and how they interact with weapons and items in D&D.

Comment: Are you talking about the PC being tiny sized, or the PC's companion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle a Tiny Player Character in 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108214/how-to-handle-a-tiny-player-character-in-5e)

Comment: If the above question does not answer your question, please [edit] your question to focus on the aspect of Tiny PCs that this other question does not cover, or does not go into enough detail about for your purposes.