Is this homebrew race balanced? I based it off of Pichu
Size: Tiny (specifically: average height is 1'00, and average weight is 4.4 lbs)
Traits: Feline Agility
Ability Score Increase: When determining your character's ability scores, increase one score by 2 and increase a different score by 1, or increase three different scores by 1.
Lightning Adept: At 1st level, you gain the "Revitalizing Jolt" cantrip, as follows:

Casting time: 1 action 
Range: Touch
Components: V, S
You send a small amount of electricity into a downed ally's body, in an attempt to awaken them. Roll a D20. If you roll a natural 1, they fail 2 death saving throws. If the total is 2-10, they fail one death saving throw. If the total is 11+, they get up with 1 hp. If you roll a natural 20, they get back up with full hp. At level 5+, add 1 to the total result, 11+, add 2, and 17+, add 2+the target's constitution modifier (minimum of+3)

At level 3, you gain the "Thunderbolt" Spell.

Casting time: 1 action 
1st level
Range: 30 feet 
Components: V, S
Damage type: lightning
Save: Dex
You shoot a bolt of lightning towards a target you can see within range. The target makes a dexterity saving throw, taking 1d8 lightning damage and having their movement speed reduced by 10 feet until the end of their next turn, or half as much damage with no slow on a success. When cast at a level above 1st, add 1d8 damage for each spell level above 1st.

You can cast this spell once per long rest without a spell slot, as well as by using any spell slots you may have.
Lightning Strike: When making an unarmed strike, you may use your bonus action to add 1d8 lightning damage to the attack. This decision must be made after you roll to hit, but before you roll for damage. At level 5, this upgrades to 2d8, at 11 it becomes 3d8, and at 17 it becomes 4d8. Once you use this benefit, you cannot do so again until the start of your next turn.
Shock step: Due to the electricity flowing through your body, you move faster than most creatures. At 1st level, your base speed is 45, at 5th level it becomes 50, at 11th level it becomes 55, and at 17th level it becomes 60. This happens independently of other increases to speed. If another affect changes your base speed to a set value, take the higher number. Your base movement speed can never go below 15.
Lightning Immune: You have immunity to lightning damage, and advantage on saving throws to resist being paralyzed.

If another affect changes your base speed to a set value, take the higher number - does this still apply to effects that set your speed to 0?!

What did you do to assess the balance of this race? Did you compare it with other published races?

What's the name of the race? Also how do you intend to use it? As a Character in regular D&D Fantasy D&D Game or for some kind of Pokémon world?

@Trish with that part, I was mostly meaning if a class feature grants a similar affect, with effects that set speed to 0, it would instead go to 15

@bmaderbacher I looked at the other races in monsters of the multiverse, and tried to treat it as if it was another race there, taking two of the three places for spells from fairy, feline agility from tabaxi, and ability Score Increase from basically all of them, and replaced the third spell from fairy for lightning strike. From there, I added shock step in place of the fairy's flight, and then added lightning Immune in place of an additional language, so unless I learn another somewhere else, I can only speak common.

@TreeSpawned I was thinking of calling it Pichu, since that's what I'm trying to make, and this is in regular DND.

Asking for a race review when it has  bunch of new powers which you have no idea on the balance of isn't a good idea. However it has been said before that given your games don't play by the rules I really don't understand why you keep asking these questions about things clearly way out of balance.

@TreeSpawned sorry, I forgot to do that. I'll do that now

It's pretty strong and its movement is broken
First let's talk about what's not a problem:

Feline Agility: A feature from an existing race, so nothing out of the ordinary.
Ability Score Improvements: Same as regular races.
Thunderbolt: Giving a Level 1 Spell at Level 3 usable once for free per day is not a problem either. Though this spell, is really  underpowered. It is pretty simular to Ray of Frost (1D8 Damage + 10 ft Slow), but that spell is a Cantrip.

And now let's talk about what is:

Revitalizing Jolt: At first glance this is basically just a variant of Spare the Dying and giving a Race a single Cantrip at level 1 is not an issue. However the ability to get back up 50% of the time is too good for a cantrip and the ability to do that at full hp if you roll a Nat 20 is broken. I think you should ditch this one entirely. It's too good for a cantrip, but is completely outshined by Cure Wounds, if we leave out the Nat 20 Feature (which we should).
Lightning Strike: 1D8 Bonus Damage, of a non-physical damage type is a lot, even if it's only once per Round and as a bonus action (you should omit one of these phrases as they are almost always mutually exclusive, as you only have one BA per round).  It is only for Unarmed Strike though, so many classes will not make use of it. But a Monk will pretty much always choose to do that bonus damage instead of his regular Martial Arts BA Unarmed Strike with that he does about the same damage, though without needing to roll for it. A Fighter with the Unarmed Fighting Fighting Style will also pretty much double their DPR with this. That's something a Race should not be able to do.
Lightning Immune: This is also really strong. Immunity to a damage from a race is way too much. Compare this to Fizban's Chromatic Dragonborn who gets it for 1 Minute per Day at level 5+. Advantage on saves against paralyzed is also unheard of, as that is one of, if not the best/worst condition.
Shock step: This is the most broken of the abilities. Typically 35 feet is the absolute maximum you can have from a race, well except for the old Aarakocra, with their 50ft flying speed, which were broken with that aswell. A race also never gives you updated abilites at such high levels, that's only reserved for classes. And finally, the thing about always taking the higher speed, is ridiculous. Because with that you would negate all of the game's conditions, that reduce your speed to 0, such as restrained and grappled. You would be able to walk at 15 ft even if someone had grappled you or you were stuck to a spider web and that's just not possible.

Lastly its size: Tiny might make sense for such a creature, but the game is designed for small and medium player characters only, even fairies are just small. Some game rules might break, but it's probaby not the end of the world.
If you wanna play a Pokémoncharacter, here's my advice:
I am running a D&D 5e Campaign set in a Pokémon World where all the players themselves are Pokémon. I'd like to explain how I run this and would advice you do it similarly.
The Race of each PC is "Pokémon". Which gives the following:

ASI as normal
Speed of 25ft or 30ft (though giving 30ft to all would not be a problem either)
Size small if below 1 meter, or medium if 1+ meter. This is not the same size ranges as the game normally uses, but it works for this format, where most of the player are below 1 meter.
Darkvision 60 ft
2 Individual abilites, which I determine together with the players, as for what makes sense for that specific Pokémon. For your Pichu you might get resistance to lighting damage or the Shocking Grasp Cantrip or maybe that Tabaxi Ability you already have or perhaps proficiency with acrobatics. 3 or 4 of those abilities might not be that bad either, but I try to keep it pretty simple.

Backgrounds are handwaved and just give proficiency with 2 Skills and maybe some item for flavor, such as a hat, though this will change when we transition to 2024 D&D, as those are way more involved with the added Feats.
And then everything else you can do comes from your class or equipment, but is reflavored to fit to your Pokémon. E.g. your Pichu might be a Tempest Cleric or Storm Sorcerer. Like in my group there is a Squirtle Artificer who uses Catapult as his "Water Gun" attack and has a "Bubble" attack as a reflavered Light Crossbow, that does bludgeoning damage.
If your are a melee character on the other hand you might not really be able to deal lighting damage at early levels, e.g. just use scratch which might work like a shortsword etc. depending on your class, but you might get the equivalent of a Magic Weapon that deals additional lightning damage at the appropriate level later on, maybe a reflavored Flame Tongue. You wouldn't get the weapon itself but you would basically "learn a new Pokémon move" which enables you attack as if your had that sword, call it "Thunder Punch" for flavor.

If I do make these changes, would bard be a good choice? I wanted to make Ukulele Pichu.

@Tasi  If you are a Bard with a normal instrument in a regular D&D World, you might not need any class reflavoring. Give it the Pokémon Race as I described and you might be good to go.

Would it work if I changed Revitalizing Jolt to where if you roll 11+ they are stable, as if it were just spare the dying, and on a natural 20 they get up with 1hp, basically working as a death save if death saves stabilized on a success?

@Tasi Yeah that seems balanced. But who would risk giving their dying ally a failed saved 50% of the time, just for the 5% chance of getting back up? You are better of just making a medicine check then.

Well, it all depends on the situation. Say you have the lucky feat, and the barbarian moves next. They have failed 2 death saving throws, and they are the only one who can do the necessary damage to the enemy to avoid a tpk, so you need them up NOW, then you may be better off with Revitalizing Jolt, using all your lucky dice to attempt to get them back up, maybe the wizard could assist with a silvery barbs too

+1 just, yup! :) ... though I did want to point out that Centaurs do have 40 ft. movement.

WAY too strong
I would never approve this species as written because it breaks fundamental game mechanics and violates basic design paradigms:
Coffin Nail #1:
The Shock Step feature, as described, breaks the following movement restriction in the game:

Grappled -
A grappled creature’s speed becomes 0, and it can’t benefit from any bonus to its speed.[..]
Restrained -
A restrained creature’s speed becomes 0, and it can’t benefit from any bonus to its speed.
Exhaustion - [level 2]: Speed halved / [level 5]: Speed reduced to 0

All of those would be ignored and set to 15, which for Grappled or restrained would ignore the whole idea of being so. No, this is not balanceable in the slightest.
Further, the base speed of 45 is way higher than any other species but for fly speeds, and going up in base speed by level is unprecedented.
As such, this ability alone makes this species impossible to be balanced against any other species: there just isn't any way to balance this.
Coffin Nail #2: Revitalizing Jolt
Let's read this carefully:
On one hand, you have a 50% chance to send them dying.
On the other hand, you are 50% of the time strictly better than spare the dying, a touch cantrip. And there's a 5% chance to be better than even Heal in a 9th spell slot, which is limited to 100 HP, while RJ can do any amount healing.
As such, this ability defies categorisation properly, but due to the potential healing amount from a cantrip - even with the 5% chance to directly  kill a 1-failed-death-save character - this is clearly better than spare the dying (which just gives stable) and even a, upcast Heal in upper levels, though way less reliable.
In either way the dice fall, this is too strong, and no ability in 5th Edition D&D has a drawback even closely similar to this. As such, this is unprecedented and unbalanceable. Further, the chances vastly improve with Lucky or similar traits allowing to reroll or roll such with advantage... it's impossible to balance this.
Coffin Nail #3: Lightning Immune
While very much on point, this is a balancing nightmare. Even the Genasi races do not gain immunity to their elements but instead do not need to breathe (air), ignore difficult terrain (earth), gain fire resistance (fire), or breathe water and air (water). This isn't calculable easily, so another nail to the coffin.
Coffin Nail #4: Lightning Strike
This one is the smallest of the problems, but it seems this is strictly better than a leveled Monk ability (Elemental Strike), which just swaps your unarmored damage, while the ability adds extra damage, starting on level 1. It seems to be combineable even, making this way overpowered. On low levels, this could even cause on average more damage than many mundane weapons, though not all.

Too Strong As Is, But Would Work With Nerfs
Size (tiny)
No particular issue with the size
Move Speed (Feline Agility/Shock Step)
The Feline Agility + Shock Step combo has WAY too much power with too few demerits even before adding class features. This'll be lengthy so I'll cover this at the end
Ability Score
I think the +2, +1 is fair, but should be socketed into specific attributes. I'd recommend mimicking the Cat Stat block here: +2 Dex, +1 Wisdom, and proficiency in Perception
Lightning Adept
Rather than being too powerful for a cantrip, I actually think the ability has too much risk involved and can kill an ally too easily. The ability seems closer to a medicine check to stabilize rather than just being an alternative to Spare The Dying, so maybe tweak it more in that direction? Like giving you advantage when using a med kit to stabilize or letting you stabilize without a med kit?
Thunderbolt
Too weak for a 1st level spell, comparable to Ray Of Frost. Couple of things you can do to balance it:

Lose it, you already have Lightning Strike
Get Lightning Bolt at Lv5. In this case you need to set which attribute is used for the spellcasting modifier since it's a racial ability rather than a class one (I recommend Wisdom or Dexterity)
Add Shocking Grasp cantrip. Personally I think this one is most in line with what you were going for. You could flavor it by adding the ability to cast it as a ranged spell a number of times per long rest equal to your proficiency bonus to get the level scaling effect. You'd still need to specify which attribute is the spellcasting modifier.

Lightning Strike
This ability is too powerful for a bonus action ability with unlimited uses, especially if you pick a melee focused class. I don't think giving it finite charges fits with the theme so weakening it is probably a safer bet to make other bonus actions equally viable.

Make it 1d4 damage with the same level scaling (+1d4 @lv5, 11 & 17), or 1d6 with half the scaling (+1d6 @lv11)
You could also have the ability proc when dealing Lightning damage instead of on a melee attack. Might end up with some interesting utility paired with Thunderbolt if you made it a modded Shocking Grasp

Lightning Immune
Too powerful even if you were to add some vulnerabilities. Either change it from immunity to resistance, make it a reaction ability, or both.
Move Speed
Too OP with negligible cost, ESPECIALLY for a racial ability. I do really like the idea, but it needs a major nerfing to make any other race viable. Here's a few ideas for balance:

Make Shock Step a concentration ability
Give Shock Step a 1 minute duration and gain a level of exhaustion after
Make Feline Agility a 1 action ability that can only be used while Shock Step is active.


I got sleepy at the end, but you get what I was going for on the movement speed

I only got as far as ASI, but you already suggeted Tiny size is fine despite it being nowhere on any other class, and you suggested tying ASI to specific stats which is the old design mechanic (and maybe the new 2024 one but meh). It looks also like you are making untested suggestions rather than a proper critique.

@SeriousBri there are already rules in DMG specifically covering Tiny player characters

@SeriousBri https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108214/how-to-handle-a-tiny-player-character-in-5e . The modified abilities are untested as you say, but they are all based on comparable level 1 race/class/subclass features

ASIs are always written like OP did since about 2020.

I just realized - the feline agility one is literally just dash with extra steps, I achieve the same result with the dash action and can do it whenever I please

Feline Agility isn't inherently broken by itself. It's main utility comes from the lack of duration; you can use it AND dash action the same turn for a fair trade-off. What makes it too powerful in this context is that Shock Step is a passive buff to movement speed, meaning you can stack all three abilities. An extreme example would be an Arcane Trickster with Haste buff: at level 5 you can dash twice in a turn with hasted action and bonus action, on top of feline Agility, with a 50ft base move speed, moving a total of 200ft w/o spending an action every other turn
